# How to get column values of a new added column with SELECT command

Tags: c#, sql, select, datagridview, datatable

I created a customer order from with Windows Forms. A customer can sign in with his ID. Once he is logged in, the DataGridView is showing the articles table with the information what articles are available and ready to order.  The data comes from an SQL database. Below you can check out the method which creates the table and how the table looks like. As you can see, after the data has been loaded into the table, I added and additional column to the table (“Bestellmenge”), which is for the amount of pieces of the article, the customer would like to order. The amount will be entered by the customer.
After he entered the amount for the articles he would like to order and clicks on the order button on the form, I want the DataGridView to show only a table with those articles he has ordered, with the columns article id, name, ordered amount, price and all round price (for each article). To calculate the all round price I need the amount of pieces and the price. However, the ordered amount is not part of a table in the SQL database, it has been created with an additional column. My question is, is it somehow possible with a SQL SELECT command to get to the amount and calculate the all round price?

```
    private string tableName = "Artikel";
    private bool update = false;

    DataGridTableStyle dgTabStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
    string sqlCmd = "SELECT * FROM artikel";

    private void ArtikelLaden()
    {
        DataTable thisTable = dataSet.Tables[tableName];
        if (thisTable != null)
        {
            thisTable.Clear();
        }


        try
        {
            odbcDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(sqlCmd, odbcConnection);
            odbcDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, tableName);
            dataGrid.SetDataBinding(dataSet, tableName);
            if (!update)
            {
                //Neue Spalte Bestellmenge hinzufügen:
                dataSet.Tables[tableName].Columns.Add("bestellmenge");

                dgTabStyle.MappingName = tableName;

                DataGridTextBoxColumn dgtCol1 = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
                dgtCol1.MappingName = "id";
                dgtCol1.ReadOnly = true;
                dgtCol1.HeaderText = "Artikel-ID";
                DataGridTextBoxColumn dgtCol2 = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
                dgtCol2.MappingName = "name";
                dgtCol2.ReadOnly = true;
                dgtCol2.HeaderText = "Artikel";
                dgtCol2.Width = 100;
                DataGridTextBoxColumn dgtCol3 = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
                dgtCol3.MappingName = "beschreibung";
                dgtCol3.ReadOnly = true;
                dgtCol3.HeaderText = "Beschreibung";
                dgtCol3.Width = 100;
                DataGridTextBoxColumn dgtCol4 = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
                dgtCol4.MappingName = "groesse";
                dgtCol4.ReadOnly = true;
                dgtCol4.HeaderText = "Größe";
                DataGridTextBoxColumn dgtCol5 = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
                dgtCol5.MappingName = "farbe";
                dgtCol5.ReadOnly = true;
                dgtCol5.HeaderText = "Farbe";
                DataGridTextBoxColumn dgtCol6 = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
                dgtCol6.MappingName = "preis";
                dgtCol6.Format = "c";
                dgtCol6.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                dgtCol6.ReadOnly = true;
                dgtCol6.HeaderText = "Preis";
                DataGridTextBoxColumn dgtCol7 = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
                dgtCol7.MappingName = "menge";
                dgtCol7.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                dgtCol7.ReadOnly = true;
                dgtCol7.HeaderText = "lieferbar";
                DataGridTextBoxColumn dgtCol8 = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
                dgtCol8.MappingName = "bestellmenge";
                dgtCol8.NullText = "";
                dgtCol8.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                dgtCol8.HeaderText = "Bestellmenge";
                dgtCol8.Width = 100;


                dgTabStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgtCol1);
                dgTabStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgtCol2);
                dgTabStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgtCol3);
                dgTabStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgtCol4);
                dgTabStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgtCol5);
                dgTabStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgtCol6);
                dgTabStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgtCol7);
                dgTabStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgtCol8);
                dataGrid.TableStyles.Add(dgTabStyle);

                update = true;
                // default-Button ändern:
                this.AcceptButton = this.buttonBestellen;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.GetType() + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to calculate the product of 2 columns in a select statement e.g.

```
| quantity| price|
|---------|------|
| 2       | 4    |
| 5       | 8    |
| 7       | 1    |
```

SELECT quantity, price, value1 * value2 AS total FROM example;

```
| quantity | price  | total |
|----------|--------|-------|
| 2        | 4      | 8     |
| 5        | 6      | 30    |
| 7        | 8      | 56    |
```

Comment: In fact it is like that yes, however, in your examples the quantity column is not part of a table in the database. It has been added after the table has been created. Let´s say all columns are part of the articles table in the database, then the command would be SELECT a.quantity, a.price value1 * value2 AS total FROM articles. But in this case a.quantity does not exist, since the customer will add this value. How can you access it?